# Stack Overflow Mobile Apps

Tags: discussion, api, mobile-web

I'm just wondering, would creating Stack Overflow Trilogy mobile applications (for iPhone, Android, etc.) be a good idea? What does the community think? Maybe, after a general API is proposed and released, the whole community could somehow get together and create such applications?

*NOTE: There have been questions before that asked whether mobile apps for Stack Overflow are currently available - this is not a duplicate, they are simply related.*

**UPDATE:** I just checked out the mobile Stack Overflow web UI, and it's spectacular! However, I still think mobile applications are a good idea. Let's say that we want to make a Stack Overflow iPhone app with the API that will be released in 6-8 weeks (of course, we'll be making it *after* the API is released, right?). Per one design, we could have these tabs/panes in the app:

- **Me** - this is where your profile info is shown, collated from all associated accounts from your login. You can see all your questions, answers, rep changes, notifications, and more for all 4 Trilogy sites. Also, we could have notifications outside of the app, based on the existing notifications architecture of Stack Overflow.
- **Questions** - questions are shown in a grid format (with a similar look and feel to the web Stack Overflow UI), the site you wish to see questions from can be selected through a little tabbed interface at the top (and there will also be tabs such as "Featured", "Unanswered", etc.), once you click on a question, it is displayed with all of its info & metadata and you can answer from inside a question, as well as vote, favorite, retag, etc.
- **Tags** - similar to the Tags interface in the web UI, but again, you can select which of the 4 sites you want to see the tags of.
- **Users** - see Tags explanation.
- **Search** - utilizes the search functions.

So, what do you think? Do you think:

- **that creating mobile apps for Stack Overflow is a good idea?**
- **that the above design is a possible implementation?**
- **What other architectures do you think would be a good idea, depending on how the API is developed?**

Comment: ? sounds like a good idea,so, is there an application for android

Answer (score 5):

Are you refering to an app that users can perform what they do from a normal browser? I've been accessing SO from my Opera Mini browser on my 2 yr+ SonyEricsson phone.Yes 2 yr old cell phone is ancient these days.

Anyway, I'm really impressed with the experience. Other than some of the Ajax stuff which are become postbacks, I can do almost anythng I want without re-adjusting to a new layout or UI.

Try it for yourself using Opera Mini Demo:

http://www.opera.com/mini/demo/

Comment: Really? I've never tried the mobile web UI! I guess I should!

Comment: @Maxim Z.: You should!

Comment: I'd also recommend Skyfire which uses Firefox + video streaming technology so it's like you're controlling Firefox from a far. SO should works exactly just like on the desktop. http://www.skyfire.com/

Answer (score 5):

Check out [StackMobile](http://stackmobile.com).

It's a lightweight way to browse all of the StackExchange sites.

Comment: It's nice but you can't login neither to ask nor to answer nor to vote

Comment: @onof: I know. It's a limitation of the StackOverflow API.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison More than a year on, it still is a limitation? I mean, we still can't exactly log in from a mobile, esp. a dumb phone (a non-smart cell phone)? What is the status today?

Comment: @Kris: Well, v2.0 of the API introduced authentication so we're one step closer.